# Colorbox Deeplink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I am working with colorbox to display video's on a single page. The problem is that i need to share an url which directly opens the colorbox with the specific video.

I searched everywhere but i dont know where to start. Do i need to pass a hash at the end of the url which will tell colorbox with video it needs to open? And how do i generate/update the url when a specific video is clicked/watched?

Thanks!

The html below is in a foreach loop. So there will be multiple figures like this with the same a class.

```
<figure>
  <a class="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VOJyrQa_WR4?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent">
      <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/VOJyrQa_WR4/mqdefault.jpg">
     <span class="play"></span>
   </a>
    <figcaption>
       <p>asdasd</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

and the JS

```
$(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:853, innerHeight:670});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i already found the solution. For the people who dont know where to start, here is the code:

HTML

```
<a id="YOUR-VID-ID" class="YOUR-COLORBOX-CLASS" href="http://example-page-to-frame">
```

JS

```
 var colorboxId = 
     (window.location.href.indexOf('video=')==-1) ?
 false :
     window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('video=') + 'video='.length + 1).split('&')[0];

$(".YOUR-COLORBOX-CLASS").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:853, innerHeight:670});

if(colorboxId!==false) {
    $('#' + colorboxId).colorbox({open:true});
}
```

Your url to get the video

```
http://example.com?video=#id
```